# How to resize ImageDraw object?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am following these instructions: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-imagedraw-draw-line/ .

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
  
w, h = 220, 190
shape = [(40, 40), (w - 10, h - 10)]
  
# creating new Image object
img = Image.new("RGB", (w, h))
  
# create line image
img1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img)  
img1.line(shape, fill ="red", width = 0)
img.show()
```

I then tried to add this line immediately before `img.show()`:

```
img1 = img1.resize((1024, 1024), Image.BOX)
```

Which is what I usually do to resize Image objects (I know, if this worked it would distort the image since it's a square, but I don't care about that right now).
When I run the code I get the `AttributeError: 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'resize'`.

So, either there is a different method to resize ImageDraw objects or I need to convert the ImageDraw object back into an Image object. In both cases I couldn't find a solution, can you help me out?

Answer (score 3):

Using

```py
img1 = img1.resize((1024, 1024), Image.BOX)
```

you're trying to call a `resize` method on some `ImageDraw` object. And, the error message tells you, that `ImageDraw` objects don't have such a method.

Let's have a look at the different modules, classes, and objects involved:

- Pillow has an [`Image`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#image-module) module providing an [`Image`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#the-image-class) class, that "represents an image object". Instances of that class, i.e. `Image` objects, have a [`resize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) method.
- Also, there is an [`ImageDraw`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#imagedraw-module) module, that "provides simple 2D graphics for `Image` objects". From the documentation on [`ImageDraw.Draw`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.Draw):

  > Creates an object that can be used to draw in the given image.
  >
  > Note that the image will be modified in place.

  The first sentence tells you, that the created `ImageDraw` object is linked to your actual `Image` object, and that any draw operation is performed in that image (`Image` object). The second sentence tells you, that any modification is instantly performed. There's no need to explicitly "update" the `Image` object, or to somehow "convert" the `ImageDraw` object (back) to some `Image` object. (It's also simply not possible.)

So, fixing your code is very easy now. Simply call `resize` on your actual `Image` object `img`, and not on your `ImageDraw` object `img1`:

```py
img = img.resize((1024, 1024), Image.BOX)
```